Why Choose Protein Powder Over Soya Chunks?
Protein powder does not justify its cost when compared to soya chunks.
Soya chunks contain all essential amino acids and are also high in fiber, which is beneficial.
Slower digestion is not an issue, as soya chunks are digested within the recovery period.
Typically, one scoop of protein powder provides 24-27 grams of protein.
In contrast, consuming 100 grams of soya chunks yields approximately 52 grams of protein.
After two hours of consumption, the digested protein amount should be roughly equal for both options: approximately 25 grams from protein powder (based on 25 grams of protein per scoop) and about 25 grams from soya chunks (which contain 52 grams of protein in 100 grams).
Therefore, I see no logical necessity to choose protein powder over soya chunks.
Cost ratio of soya chunks to protein powder = 13:2 or 13:1


one scoop of protein powder provides 24-27 grams of protein.


100 grams of soya chunks yields approximately 52 grams of protein.

Clever little shell game you pulled there. A scoop of powder is something like 30g. The goat whey powder I use has ~80 grams of protein per 100 grams -- significantly more than your chunky bois. Also worth noting the difference in carb content.
If it's a question of cost, then decide based on cost and simply remain aware of the other tradeoffs.

The fact is no one takes 100g scoop of protein powder. Everyone takes 30-36g scoop of protein powder. Carb is not an issue if overall carb you're consuming is in your healthy limit. I still don't see any single benefit of choosing protein powder over soya chunks.

@Luffy It's misleading to compare 100g of one thing to 30g of another thing. Why do that?

@Luffy One benefit of whey powder is that it is higher protein per gram. Another is that it contains negligible carbohydrate, which is often desirable.

It's not misleading. Most people consume 50-100g of soya chunks per day. On the other hand, most people do not consume more than 30-36g of protein powder per day. It is totally fine to compare this way. However, comparing 30g soya chunks to 30g protein powder — would be misleading.

Whey powder's higher protein concentration, if compared to soya chunks, neither justify its cost nor its nutritional values. We should compare what we're getting overall from 100g of soya chunks vs 32g of whey protein powder. Whey protein only makes sense if your body needs protein immediately which is not the case most of the time. 30g carbs in 100g soya chunks is not a big deal.

@Luffy "30g carbs in 100g soya chunks is not a big deal." I suspect that depends on your goals.  What is the difference in calories between the two?  The protein supplement I use is about 200 calories per 40g of protein.

@Luffy Most people consume protein power as a supplement to get, well, proteins. They most of the time are not their main source of protein. Thus, the goal is to get as much protein for the least of calories or the least of food amount to eat or cook. Replacing protein powder for soya chunks would lead to consuming more food to reach the desired amount of protein which most of the time is not the wanted thing.
